# Find a string with regex of unknown length begnning with a specific string

Tags: regex

I'm looking find a string of unknown length that beings with `abc.` The strings end is defined by a space, the end of a line, the end of the file, etc.

The string may contain `.` characters in the middle.

Examples of what I'm trying to find include:

`abc.hello.1.test.a`

`abc.1test.hello.b.maybe`

`abc.myTest.1.test.maybe`

Characters after the first dot must be present, so the following would not match.

`abc.`

`abc`

Comment: i guess `^abc\.?[a-zA-Z]+.*`

Comment: Please fix the many typos in your question. Also, what terminates the string of unknown length?

Comment: been trying variations on `^(abc\.)+` but `^(abc\.)+*` doesn't work.  @Pavneet_Singh suggestion is close but I'd like it to stop at a space.

Comment: @agf1997, from a regex standpoint, space is very different from end of line or end of file, people answering your question have no idea what other conditions are meant when you say "ect."

Comment: @Austin_Anderson maybe I generalize my question a little too much.  I'm trying to use the regex expression in conjunction with a string restriction in an XSD schema.  Bottom line is that I want to make sure the string in the element in question starts with `abc.` but isn't just `abc.`  Does this make more sense?

Comment: so i think the below answer should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this Pattern `(abc\.\S+)` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YeSJP7/1)

```
(               # Capturing Group (1)
  abc           # "abc"
  \.            # "."
  \S            # <not a whitespace character>
  +             # (one or more)(greedy)
)               # End of Capturing Group (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really just want `abc.{any non empty string}` its trivial to do `^abc\..+$`  which just finds `abc.` at the beginning, and then matches 1 or more of anything after that

If you want `abc.{any string without a space}` its similar, `^abc\.[^ ]+$`

the `^` and `$` are called anchors, and make sure your regex is matching the whole string, instead of say, `efg.abc.hij`